# How do I consume multiple outputs of `textscan` function in a single line?

Tags: string, matlab, parsing, textscan

Suppose I have the following string:

> s = 'Foo 1.000 3.000 3.554'

I would like to read it with the `textscan` function as follows.

> [name x y z] = textscan(s, '%s %f %f %f')

However, when I do this, I always get the `Too many output arguments` error.

I think it has to do with the fact that `textscan` outputs a cell array, but I could not discover how to work around this problem and the desired effect.

Comment: You cannot do that with a call to `textscan()`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need two lines to do what you want. First you get the desired valued into a dummy variable, then  distribute the data with `deal`:

```
dummy = textscan(s, '%s %f %f %f');
[a,b,c,d] = deal(dummy {:});
```