# Combine multiple answers into variable(s) in Octave

Tags: octave

Consider:

```
textscan('5,6,7', '%s', 'Delimiter',','){1}{1:3}
ans = 55
ans = 66
ans = 77
```

Excellent! Now I want those three answers in different variables, or some structure I can do things with.

So I try:

```
X = textscan('55,66,77', '%s', 'Delimiter',','){1}{1:3}
X = 55
```

Only one value.

So I try:

```
X = [textscan('55,66,77', '%s', 'Delimiter',','){1}{1:3}] '
X = 556677
```

It's made it into one string.

So I try:

```
X Y Z = textscan('55,66,77', '%s', 'Delimiter',','){1}{1:3}
  ^
syntax error
```

There must be some way to handle multiple answers ... but how?

Comment: Why do you need them as separate variables?

Comment: `[a,b,c]` is how you get multiple variables as output in MATLAB, as you can see in almost all documentation pages of MATLAB. However, `texscan` does not support multiple separated variables as output, as you can clearly see in the documentation.

Comment: Use a single variable containing an array with three values. [Using dynamic variables is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170).

Comment: Parsing with `'%f'` or `'%d'` instead of `'%s'` would probably help. You want numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

This question originally was asked mistakely about MATLAB, while it's about Octave.

The answer to the question, as @excaza wrote in the comments is:

```
[a, b, c] = textscan('5,6,7', '%d%d%d', 'Delimiter', ','){:};
```

---

The first answer, that I wrote for MATLAB use is this:

You need to define three separate outputs inside `textscan`:

```
a = textscan('5,6,7', '%s%s%s', 'Delimiter', ',');
[b, c, d] = a{:}

b =
    '5'
c =
    '6'
d =
    '7'
```

If you want the output as numbers and not as text, you can use `%d`:

```
a = textscan('5,6,7', '%d%d%d', 'Delimiter', ',');
[b, c, d] = a{:}

b =
      5
c =
      6
d =
      7
```

Comment: Works, but how'd you extend this when the OP has a thousand, or a million numbers? (Not that that's the question, but for the sake of generallity)

Comment: First, I answered the question... But you right, I also agree (and voted already..) with your and others comments on the question about handling with just one variable.  But sometimes, for some reasons, I do need the separate variables,( if it's up to 3 or 4, not thousands...), so it sounds reasonable enough to me...

Comment: Muh, you could just use `b(1)` for the first number, `b(2)` for the second etc. There are your "separate" variables. Read in cleanly, not cluttering your workspace and easy to use.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason that I'm agree with you. But if I had a shared big code, for example, that has already some parameters or variables, and I want to work with it, so it's sometimes is needed.

Comment: @Adiel thanks for the reply, I'm using Octave not Matlab and it turns out it handles this differently. Thanks for being nice. ans =
{
  [1,1] = 5
} ans= ... etc.

Thanks, I'm done with this question and place tho

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with Octave. If my answer does not help for that purpose I will delete it. Can someone confirm it?

Comment: @Adiel There is no difference. Octave does support indexing into intermediate arrays, so you can do `[a, b, c] = textscan('5,6,7', '%d%d%d', 'Delimiter', ','){:};`, which provides the desired result. He's probably getting the different answer because he's still parsing it with `%s` and not with a numeric flag.

Comment: @excaza See my edit. Now I think that question can be defined and tagged as Octave\Matlab. what do you think?

Comment: It's not exactly a profound question. There are plenty of similar MATLAB questions already, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126438/how-do-i-consume-multiple-outputs-of-textscan-function-in-a-single-line)